# Google Calender API return 404 not found on inserting new Entry to CalenderList?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Inserting An entry to CalenderList returns "404 not found".
the request is as follows:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList
```

Request Body:

```
 {  
    "summary":"test Calender",
    "id":"test@google.com",
    "defaultReminders":[
          {
             "minutes":2,
             "method":"email"
          }
       ]
    }
```

The response doesn't have any good explanation on the Error. Just the "Not Found".

What may have went wrong?